# Material UI Date Picker Calendar Open Immediately On Page Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, calendar, material-ui

I have a calendar from Material UI which only opens when I click on it so it starts like this

[image]

And then opens to this

[image]

Is there anyway I can have it so that it is immediately open as soon as the page renders? I am not sure if I am missing some prop which material gives to us out of the box or if there is another way I can have it open all the time.

Here's what I have so far (straight from there docs)

```
 <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          disableToolbar
          variant="inline"
          format="MM/dd/yyyy"
          margin="normal"
          id="date-picker-inline"
          label="Date picker inline"
          value={date}
          // onChange={handleDateChange}
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            'aria-label': 'change date',
          }}
        />


      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use `open` prop. Here is an example.

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <KeyboardDatePicker
      open
      disableToolbar
      variant="inline"
      format="MM/dd/yyyy"
      margin="normal"
      id="date-picker-inline"
      label="Date picker inline"
      value={date}
      // onChange={handleDateChange}
      KeyboardButtonProps={{
        'aria-label': 'change date',
      }}
    />


  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

If you want to control it with state then create a state variable with default to true.

```
this.state = { isDatePickerOpen: true };
```

Then use the state to open and close the picker.

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <KeyboardDatePicker
      open={this.state.isDatePickerOpen}
      disableToolbar
      variant="inline"
      format="MM/dd/yyyy"
      margin="normal"
      id="date-picker-inline"
      label="Date picker inline"
      value={date}
      // onChange={handleDateChange}
      KeyboardButtonProps={{
        'aria-label': 'change date',
      }}
    />


  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Comment: So this worked and the calendar is now open on render but now it is opening with some weird css configurations in a random part of my screen
```
top: 361px;
left: 284px;
```
But then when I change any prop and hot reload the css goes away and everything is fine but on refresh the css is all messed up. Any idea why? Thanks